# Android with maven get duplicate dependency

Tags: java, android, maven

I use [maven-android-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/), and I get duplicate dependency.

I don't know which dependency should be exclude.

My `pom.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.hello</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-maven-android</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.14</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0-rc.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>19</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <extractDuplicates>true</extractDuplicates>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I get below error when I use `mvn package`:

```
[INFO] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[INFO] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/impl/NoOpLog;
```

I search this information, it seems that there are duplicate library. Now, I think:

1. Maven should deal with this problem, right?
2. I find the command causing error below, I do not find duplicate library.

> /bin/sh -c cd /Users/diplab/Documents/workspace/engineonandroid &&
>   /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   -Xmx1024M -jar /opt/Android/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/19.1.0/lib/dx.jar --dex
>   --output=/Users/diplab/Documents/workspace/engineonandroid/target/classes.dex
>   /Users/diplab/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-asm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
>   /Users/diplab/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4.1/mail-1.4.1.jar
>   /Users/diplab/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
>   /Users/diplab/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.9/jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.jar
>   /Users/diplab/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.2/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
>   /Users/diplab/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar
>   /Users/diplab/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
>   /Users/diplab/Documents/workspace/engineonandroid/target/classes
>   /Users/diplab/.m2/repository/org/activiti/activiti-bpmn-converter/5.14/activiti-bpmn-converter-5.14.jar
>   /Users/diplab/.m2/repository/org/mybatis/mybatis/3.2.2/mybatis-3.2.2.jar
>   /Users/diplab/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.1/joda-time-2.1.jar
>   /Users/diplab/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar
>   /Users/diplab/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
>   /Users/diplab/.m2/repository/org/activiti/activiti-engine/5.14/activiti-engine-5.14.jar
>   /Users/diplab/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-email/1.2/commons-email-1.2.jar
>   /Users/diplab/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.2/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.2.jar
>   /Users/diplab/.m2/repository/org/activiti/activiti-bpmn-model/5.14/activiti-bpmn-model-5.14.jar

What should I do?